# RPM Spec file diagnostics

Tags: linux, centos-7, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm writing a spec file and getting slightly unexpected results when I install the rpm. I'd like to see what the install process thinks it's doing.

Contrived example, suppose I have:

```
   %install
   mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{somedir}
   cp nice.file %{buildroot}%{somedir}
```

and the rpm install succeeds but nice.file is not where I expect it to be - yes in this contrived example that surely can't happen, but I have a fair few more things going on ...

So add some diagnostic:

```
   %install
   mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{somedir}
   echo "about to copy to %{buildroot}%{somedir}"
   cp nice.file %{buildroot}%{somedir}
   ls %{buildroot}%{somedir}
```

which all shows up nicely when I build the rpm, but at install time I see nothing.

Is there a way to get some diagnostic output? Better still an explicit trace of the execution steps?

I'm on Centos 7 right now, but interested across any platform that uses rpms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%install section does **nothing** during installation. This section is used to install build artifact into the proper location in %buildroot so %files section can pick them up later.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557015/build-rpm-to-just-install-files and https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#working-with-spec-files